# Append Choices to GrammarBuilder object strange behaviour

Tags: speech-recognition

Let's say I want to fit this regular expression in a Choice object *total_choice* that will be part of a greater grammar:  **value ( [3-9][0-9] | [1-7][0-9] )** 
And this is how I build it:

```
Choices total_choice= new Choices(); 
Choices all_digits = new Choices(new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" });

// value [3-9][0-9]
gb_aux = new GrammarBuilder("value");
gb_aux.Append( new Choices(new string[] { "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" }));
gb_aux.Append(all_digits);
total_choice.Add(gb_aux);

// value  [1-7][0-9]
gb_aux = new GrammarBuilder("value");
gb_aux.Append(new Choices(new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" }));
gb_aux.Append(all_digits);   ///// <------
total_choice.Add(gb_aux);
```

The problem appears with the sentence with the arrow. If I uncomment it, the program crashes. I make the same just some lines before, and I can't see why there's a problem now and not before.

Note: I know it's not the most optimum way to build the grammar, I just simplified the thing to focus in the problem.

---

To answer Nikolay's suggestion let me be more specific. The thing is that I need to recognize "flight level" followed by a number [30, 700]. But pilots don't say "fourty", they say "four zero", that's why I separate the digits like that. I understand that Nikolay suggests me to build a simpler grammar (three consecutive digits) and control the range at another level. I like the idea. So I do:

```
// flight level [0-9][0-9][0-9]
   gb_aux = new GrammarBuilder("flight level");
   gb_aux.Append(new Choices(new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" }));
   gb_aux.Append(new Choices(new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" }));
   gb_aux.Append(new Choices(new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" }));
   level_choices.Add(gb_aux);
```

But then there's the same problem as before, when I append the second set of digits. Well it doesn't crash, in fact the interface never launches. Realize that now I don't re-use the all_digits object, I create a new one each time.

---

Another try, this one jumps to the rejected method when I'm saying the second digit (and then crashes):

```
  gb_aux = new GrammarBuilder("flight level");
  Regex reg = new Regex(@"^\d\d\d?$"); //also tried "^\s?\d\s\d\s\d?\s?$"
  Choices chose = new Choices();
  chose.Add(reg.ToString());
  gb_aux.Append(chose);
```

Comment: I would add two new questions about problems you have, they are not really related to the original problem. In second issue you can use Append with count argument instead of appending three times. Third issue just about regular expressions not being supported.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That of the count argument put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Although I'm still not sure why some of the things I tried didn't work.

```
   GrammarBuilder level = new GrammarBuilder();
   level.Append("flight level", 0, 1); //"flight level" is optional
   Choices digits = new Choices(new string[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" });
   level.Append(digits, 2, 3); //minimum 2 digits, maximum 3 digits
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not append `all_choices` twice, you have to create new choices.

Overall, you should never design very complex grammars. Users will never follow them and recognizer will have hard time. Allow user to say arbitrary sequence of digits and parse the speech recognition result with a regular expression. In case digit sequence does not match just warn the user. This allows you to wait for the input too if partial string was recognized.

By enforcing strict and complex grammar you loose the ability to recognize and handle user errors.

Comment: Ok, I think I get the idea, but let me me be more specific, I'm editing, to add code.